# Returning 403 from custom exception type in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-errors

I want to restrict some pages on my site depending on user permissions saved in the database.

The error will originate in the service/data access layer.

I have discovered that if I throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` then the status code returned by the asp.net pipeline is 401, which results in a YSOD instead of going to the MVC custom error page.

From reading around it seems that I need to be returning 403 error instead. I have created a custom exception type to use in place of `UnauthorizedAccessException`. How do I configure MVC to return 403 response on this error? How do I then set the filter to redirect to my custom forbidden page on this error? Am I taking the correct approach?

Comment: One way which I handled 403 was; in Application_Error after all logging etc., check the error code, if it is 403,  redirect it to 403 action in Errors controller which shows a nice custom view for 403 erros.

Comment: Will watch this space for better ideas.

Comment: @Yahya but how to force MVC to interpret error as 403 status?

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2578795/125740

Comment: Your custom exception type should inherit from `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider Authentication build into asp.net MVC... 
The thing is that you can just add `[Authorize]` attribute to your controller or 
`[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]` for users and `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]` for groups.

Link to [MSDN article for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx). And a tutorial for [auth in mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)