# Extend ASP Identity Role to add group(company)

Tags: database, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

How can I extend ASP Identity 2.2 Roles, **to support isolated roles in their own groups**, such as company1, company2 etc.

I am trying to scope and limit roles to a Company, such that each company can administer their own roles and have similarly named roles - under the company purview only.

[I looked around and could not find a simpleway to extend the roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944647/asp-net-identity-custom-with-group-based-roles)

In the samples, while it shows how to extend user profiles easily, it fails to do so on the roles side of the house!