# How to return custom message if Authorize fails in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, authorize-attribute

In my WebAPI project, I have number of apis which are decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomers()
{
   //my api
}
```

In case user doesn't have the right token, an access denied exception is returned to the user.

But what I need is that in any such case, I need to return the custom response message as.

```
{
  "StatusCode" : 403,
  "message": "You donot have sufficient permission"
}
```

How do I return this custom message in case authorization fails.

Please note:

- *I am using Owin - Token based authentication.*
- *I am **not** storing the access token in my database or anywhere else.*

Comment: have a read of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/owin-unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578756/how-to-make-authorize-attribute-return-custom-403-error-page-instead-of-redirect

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are different ways to do this but one of the best way could be custom authorization attributes.You just need to inherit the `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()` method of it.

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
            Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource")
        };
    }
}
```

and use this like(`CustomAuthorization` should be used in-place of `Authorize`)

```
    [CustomAuthorization]       
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Otherwise you can also catch the status code in client side and display the custom message of your choice.

Comment: Thanks mate :) It addressed my requirement. As you mentioned there are number of ways, I would be grateful if you can add one more way

Comment: other ways could be handle exception in client side or handle exception in global application level but the best way I mention above as per my knowledge

Comment: Okay. Sounds great. Once again Thanks :)

Comment: how can this be done in .net core?? have been searching but everything seems to move towards cliams and policys. Just need something simple like this? Thanks

Comment: This no longer works with MVC 5 as HandleUnauthorizedRequest takes a parameter of type System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext

Comment: What is solution in .net core 5?