# How to add custom 401 error message in ASP .NET core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my controller code.
my controller return 401 status code successfully.

**How to return a 401 error message with my custom message**

```
[HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "reader")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllBlogsAsync()
        {
            // get data from repository
            var blogs = await blogRepository.GetAllAsync();

            // mapping Domain to DTO
            var blogsDTO = mapper.Map<List<Models.DTO.Blog>>(blogs);

            // return results
            return Ok(blogsDTO);
        }
```

My expected Output is "401 UnAuthorized"

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Unauthorized`  method like below to return.

```
return Unauthorized("401 UnAuthorized");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a custom implementation of the attribute as explained in this post:

[How to return custom message if Authorize fails in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505523/how-to-return-custom-message-if-authorize-fails-in-webapi)